# how to loop through elements using generator and make transformation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am trying to get a better understanding on how to use `generator` in python

Assuming that i have the function below:

```
names = ["john \t", " dave", "ana", " jenny"]


def function_for_generator(names):

    transformed_names = []

    for name in names:
        if name.endswith("\t"):
            cleaned_name = name.rstrip("\t").replace(" ", "")
            transformed_names.append(cleaned_name)
        elif name.startswith(" "):
            cleaned_name = name.lstrip()
            transformed_names.append(cleaned_name)
        else:
            transformed_names.append(name)
    return transformed_names
```

and the current result after calling this function: `['john', 'dave', 'ana', 'jenny']`

I was able to rewrite something close to that using a `while loop` and an `iterator` but the solution i am looking for is to rewrite this function using a `generator` specifically?

If anyone could help me rewrite that function using a `generator` with a `for loop` or `while loop`, for my own understanding, thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want the function to *generate*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for the generator function you were expecting:

```
names = ["john \t", " dave", "ana", " jenny"]

def function_for_generator(names):
    for name in names:
        if name.endswith("\t"):
            cleaned_name = name.rstrip("\t").replace(" ", "")
            yield cleaned_name
        elif name.startswith(" "):
            cleaned_name = name.lstrip()
            yield cleaned_name
        else:
            yield name
```

You can iterate over this generator function, like this:

```
for x in function_for_generator(names):
    print(x)
```

Or like this:

```
transformed_names = [x for x in function_for_generator(names)]
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i wanted to understand, how to handle the `yield` with different values in a `for loop`

Answer (score 1):

Given the specific values in your question then:

```
names = ["john \t", " dave", "ana", " Jenny"]

def function_for_generator(names):
  for name in names:
    yield name.strip()

for name in function_for_generator(names):
  print(name)
```

Or, if you just want a new list then:

```
newlist = list(function_for_generator(names))
```

This works because strip() removes both leading and trailing whitespace